# Counting how many times "\n" is in an inputted string

Tags: java, newline

I currently have a working for loop but when I try doing

```
if(input.substring(i,i++)=="\n")){
   space ++;
}
```

or the same thing with .equals it still never adds one.

Thanks

Comment: What is your complete code ? i++ adds one to i and replace the value of i by i+1 are you sure you want to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

For sure you should not use `==` operator. Then I doubt that the `equals` does not work. 
The crucial point is that "\n" is a `char`. Consider this code, then choose the option you preafer

```
String input = "a\n";
String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

// return 2 because the string contains 2 chars: "a" and "\n"
System.out.println("CharArraysLenIs: " + input.toCharArray().length);

// return true because it compares the strings on char long each
System.out.println("WithEquals_1_Is: " + input.substring(1,2).equals(newLine)); 

// return true because it compares the strings on char long each
System.out.println("WithEquals_2_Is: " + input.substring(1,2).equals("\n"));

// return false because it copares the location in memory. 
// They are really different objects (strings) in the java heap.
System.out.println("WithEqualOperatorIs: " + (input.substring(1,2) == "\n"));
```

Comment: Why not use `charAt`?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas yes you can simply it became less easy to read   `// return true  System.out.println("WithNewLine_Is: " + (input.charAt(1) == newLine.charAt(0)));  // return 0 which means equal (-1 less, 1 greater)      System.out.println("WithNewLine_Is: " + Character.compare(input.charAt(1), newLine.charAt(0)));`

Comment: Why are you doing `newline.charAt(0)`? just check `input.charAt(1) == '\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct:

```
if(input.substring(i,i++)=="\n")){
   space ++;
}
```

returns an empty string because beginIndex and endIndex are equal in your case. This is because i++ will increment i after the variable has been evaluated and used. To make your code work, change i++ to ++i and use equals not ==, or change "\n" to '\n' and substring to charAt:

```
if(input.substring(i,++i).equals("\n")){
   space ++;
}
```

or

```
if(input.charAt(i++) == '\n'){
   space ++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, [you shouldn't compare strings with `==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java). Furthermore, the pre- and post-incrementing operators are completely wrong here. As @Maxime mentioned in the comment, the `i++` increments the value stored in `i`. So what is happening is you're taking `substring(1,1)` then `substring(2,2)`, etc. which all return empty strings of length 0. (Don't believe me? [Try it yourself here](https://www.ideone.com/i91Hcl).)

Since you have a working for-loop, as you mention, you can just use the `charAt` method to get the character at the position, and then use `==` to compare the character (not string) to `'\n'`.

Eg.

```
if (input.charAt(i) == '\n') {
  space++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private static int countLines(String str){
   String[] lines = str.split("\n");
   return  lines.length-1;
}
```

This might help you.